# Find the probability that $Z_1$ is less than $Z_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)'\sim N_3(\mu,\sum)$ where $\mu=(1,-1,3)'$ and 
$$\sum= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 3 & 10\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad $$

and define $Z=(Z_1,Z_2)'$,  where $Z_1=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3$, $Z_2=3Y_1+Y_2-2Y_3$.

Find the probability that $Z_1$ is less than $Z_2$

What I have so far: 
We have to find $P(Z_1<Z_2)$

$Z$ has a normal distribution with mean $\begin{pmatrix} 3\\-4\\\end{pmatrix} \quad $ and variance $\begin{pmatrix} 21 & -14\\-14 & 45\\\end{pmatrix}. \quad $ Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Note that in MathJax a standard usage is $Y\sim N$, not $Y$~$N$. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: If you already know that $Z\sim N(\mu_Z, \Sigma_Z)$, then $$P(Z1<Z2) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz_2\int_{-\infty}^{z_2}dz_1n(z_1,z_2; \mu_Z, \Sigma_Z)$$ where $n(\cdots)$ is the normal density function.

Comment: FYI, the answer you accepted one minute after it was posted, is wrong. This could help you come to the conclusion that accepting answers instantly is a bad idea.

Comment: @Did you're right. deleting my answer so others wont make the same mistake (which was that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ have to be independent to say that the sum is normal as well)

Comment: @AlainChau Actually, $Z_1-Z_2$ **is** normal although $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are not independent.

Comment: @Did ohhh, but its variance isn't as simple as $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$? since you need the covariance term..

Comment: @AlainChau Yes, this is the aspect that your answer was missing.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb P(Z_1<Z_2)=\mathbb P(Z_1-Z_2<0)$$
where $$Z_1-Z_2=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3-(3Y_1+Y_2-2Y_3)=-2Y_1+3Y_3\sim N(7,\,94)$$
since $$\mathbb E[-2Y_1+3Y_3]=-2\cdot 1+3\cdot 3 = 7$$
and $$\text{Var}[-2Y_1+3Y_3]=(-2)^2\text{Var}Y_1+(3^2)\text{Var}Y_3+2\text{cov}(-2Y_1,3Y_3) = 4\cdot 1+9\cdot 10-12\cdot 0=94.$$
Then 
$$\mathbb P(Z_1-Z_2<0)=\Phi\left(\frac{0-4}{\sqrt{94}}\right)\approx 0.34.$$